# ninja: fatal: CreateProcess: Access is denied. in windows 10

Tags: c++, cmake, build

the repo i'm trying to build is https://github.com/svenstaro/glsl-language-server

this is the error i get

```
glsl-language-server [ master][△ v3.22.3]
❯ cmake -Bbuild -GNinja
-- The C compiler identification is unknown
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 11.2.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - failed
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/cygwin64/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/cygwin64/bin/cc - broken
CMake Error at C:/Users/hitus/scoop/apps/cmake/3.22.3/share/cmake-3.22/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:69 (message):
  The C compiler

    "C:/cygwin64/bin/cc"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: E:/software/glsl-language-server/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command(s):C:/Users/hitus/scoop/shims/ninja.exe cmTC_f7f6a &&
    CreateProcess failed. Command attempted:
    "C:\cygwin64\bin\cc    -o CMakeFiles\cmTC_f7f6a.dir\testCCompiler.c.obj -c E:\software\glsl-language-server\build\CMakeFiles\CMakeTmp\testCCompiler.c"
    ninja: fatal: CreateProcess: Access is denied.






  CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:2 (project)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "E:/software/glsl-language-server/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "E:/software/glsl-language-server/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

running `c++` works

```
glsl-language-server [ master][△ v3.22.3]
❯ c++
c++: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

but running `cc` doesn't

```
ResourceUnavailable: Program 'cc' failed to run: An error occurred trying to start process 'C:\cygwin64\bin\cc' with working directory 'E:\software\glsl-language-server'. No application is as
sociated with the specified file for this operation.At line:1 char:1
+ cc
+ ~~.
```

i'm using powershell 7 and cygwin, ninja and cmake are installed from scoop

Comment: Add C:\cygwin64\bin to exclusions of Windows Defender. I don't know what scoop is. Are you sure you may trust their software?

Comment: scoop is a package manager for windows, and well trusted and uptodate (https://scoop.sh) and i've disabled windows defender, still the same error appears

Comment: Other antivirus softwares?

Comment: no, i dont have any other anti virus, also e: is not read only (still i copied the folder c: and got the same error), and running from elevated console also doesn't help